# Immutability in Java

Tags: java

If my class is going to be an immutable one it has to be `final` and without any method that modifies its state and all properties must be private. But why should it have properties declared as `final` (for example, `private final int a`)?

**Edit**

Will the class still be an immutable one if it has a reference to objects that are not immutable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Jeremy Manson's blog post [Immutability in Java](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/04/immutability-in-java.html):

> Now, in common parlance, immutability
>   means "does not change". Immutability
>   doesn't mean "does not change" in
>   Java. It means "is transitively
>   reachable from a final field, has not
>   changed since the final field was set,
>   and a reference to the object
>   containing the final field did not
>   escape the constructor".

Manson co-authored the Java Memory Model spec, so should be knowing what he is talking about.

An example from the Brian Goetz's [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.briangoetz.com/pubs.html) book:

```
public Holder holder;
public void initialize() { holder = new Holder(42); }

publc class Holder {
  private int n;
  public Holder(int n) { this.n = n; }

  public void assertSanity() {
    if (n != n) {
      throw new AssertionError(”This statement is false”);
    }
  }
}

// Thread 1:             // Thread 2:
initialize();            if (holder != null) holder.assertSanity();
```

Thread 2 above can throw the `AssertionError`. To avoid such visibility issues the field `n` of `Holder` class should have been declared `final`.

EDIT: Consider the sequence of steps:

1. Allocate memory for new object of type `Holder`
2. Initialize field `n` of the new object
3. Execute the constructor
4. Assign the reference of the new object to `holder` reference

This is the "sane" sequence of events and the JMM (Java Memory Model) guarantees that this is what the thread calling `initialize()` will see. But, since there is no synchronization, JMM makes no guarantees about what sequence the second thread calling `holder.assertSanity()` will see. In particular, the `AssertionError` will be thrown if the second thread sees the sequence:

1. `holder` is non-null, so that it could call `assertSanity` method
2. The first read of `n` results in 0, the default value of an `int` field
3. The second read of `n` results 42

In short, when an object's constructor returns in one thread, another thread might not see all field initializations of that object. To guarantee that the second thread sees the correctly initialized fields, you should either make them `final`, or do a mutex unlock (i.e. `initialize()` method should be `synchronized`) or do a `volatile` write (i.e. `holder` should be `volatile`).

Comment: it's not clear for me why itcan throw an exception in example above. Can you explain?

Answer (score 6):

A final class is one that cannot be subclassed.  The final keyword on a class definition does not necessarily make the class immutable.  So your class does not have to be final for instances of it to be immutable (your question implies that you are making the class final, note that final can be used to modify more than just classes).  However, if you make a class final that class cannot be subclassed, so you are guaranteed that no mutable subclasses can be created.

Immutability simply means that no values on the class can be changed.  So private fields, no non-private setters should do it.  One common issu is if your class has a Collection, you have to return some sort of unmodifiable collection, else the values in the collection can be changed, even though noone could change *the reference* to the collection. This answers the second part of your question.  If declare a `final myCollection` on your class, you can't change the reference to myCollection, but you can still modify the collection outside of the class, if you have a getter (which is fine) and don't return an unmodifiable collection.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection(java.util.Collection)

With respect to immutability, keep in mind that the goal is to make it impossible to change instances of a class, once the values are initially set.  Using the final keyword can help, but is not by itself sufficient to have an immutable definition.

Comment: First paragraph is incorrect. Making the immutable class final ensures that mutable subclasses cannot be created. This allows recipients of references to the immutable class type to rely on the actual object being immutable. Joshua Bloch makes this point in "Effective Java."

Comment: @andy, but nothing about having a final class makes instances of the class unmodifiable.  Aren't there cases where one could want subclasses of an immutable class?  I agree that it is a way to insure that you can't have a mutable subclass

Comment: A big part of what makes immutability useful is that recipients of an object of immutable type can rely on the actual object being immutable. (For example, a class that receives a type it uses as a key in a map.) Subclasses could be mutable. So final classes do have something to do with immutability -- they're one part of guaranteeing.

Comment: Second paragraph, second sentence - Bloch lists several other practices to guarantee immutable behavior, like defensive copying of objects passed to constructors or returned.

Comment: @andy, yes, i reformulated my first paragraph to incorporate your comment ideas about final classes in there...The main idea of immutability on classes means that once set, the values cannot be changed.  You can write a book (well at least a healthy chapter) on best practices for immutability, which is out of the scope of this answer.  Ill still modify my answer slightly to indicate that collections are not the only thing to worry about...

Answer (score 6):

If you mark a private member variable as `final`, you enlist the compiler and runtime engine to ensure that its value can never be modified, neither by the class itself or its subclasses.

Comment: if I write the class I will not modified the value in its class(if I want the class to be immutable); there will not be any subclasses of the class, because I marked it as final, so nobody can modify the variable

Comment: @maks, if the values are not changed by your class, then the compiler verification is harmless. If you -- or someone modifying the class after you -- accidentally modify a variable in a class you presume immutable, then the compiler verification is priceless.

Answer (score 1):

It is not strictly required that the properties of an immutable class are final. If the immutable class is itself final, and you take care not to change the properties after construction, it is legal to not have those properties final.

There is however no reason to have them not final. Making them final allows the compiler to check your code and prevent accidental modification. It also documents the fact that you don't want those properties to be written more than once (on creation).

Comment: So it is not a rule, but recomendation(to declare variables as final)? if I declare private variable as final and will try to assign a new value to it in my class will I get a compile-time error?

Comment: @maks That's right. There is 1 case I know of where `final` is _required_. That is usinga local variable (declared in a method) in an anonymous inner class in that same method (like you'd do with Swing Listeners). It needs to be final as the listener is called in a time and place far away, and that variable just doesn't exist anymore when the call to the listener is done.