# How does making a field as final on an object avoids a thread seeing a null reference on that same object?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

An abstract/snippet from Java Concurrency In Practice-

```
// Unsafe publication
public Holder holder;

public void initialize(){
    holder = new holder(42);
}
```

> Two things can go wrong with improperly published objects. Other
>   threads could see a stale value for the holder field, and thus see a
>   **null** reference or other older value even though a value has been
>   placed in holder. But far worse, other threads could see an **up-todate
>   value for the holder reference, but stale values for the state of the
>   Holder**. To make things even less predictable, a thread may see a
>   stale value the first time it reads a field and then a more up-to-date
>   value the next time, which is **why assertSanity can throw
>   AssertionError**.

*Also object reference becomes visible to another thread does not necessarily mean that the state of that object is visible to the consuming thread*

```
public class Holder{
    private int n;

    public Holder(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void assertSanity(){
        if (n != n)
            throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
    }
}
```

Ofcouse, one of the ways to fix it would be to do/ make

```
public volatile Holder holder;
```

The author suggests a different approach-

> If Holder were immutable, assertSanity could not throw
>   AssertionError, even if the Holder was not properly published.)

```
public class Holder{
        private final int n;
//...
}
```

*But how? The unsafe publication is still there. I think it is still possible for a thread to get a **null** reference on holder. Please suggest.*

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107683/improper-publication-of-java-object-reference and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6088679/1743880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jls describes the special semantics of final fields

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

> final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization. A thread-safe immutable object is seen as immutable by all threads, even if a data race is used to pass references to the immutable object between threads. [...]. final fields must be used correctly to provide a guarantee of immutability.

But i suggest you read the whole chapter 17.5

"must be used correctly" refers to constructor has actually ended (and did not escaped `this`) and no fiddling with reflection.

Translated from http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/EffectiveJava/38.JMM-Overview/38.JMM-Overview.html that is:

> The end of the constructor causes a partial flush, writing all final variables and dependend objects into memory. [...]. The first reading access of a final variable causes a partial refresh, loading the final variables and depending objects from memory. Another refersh does not occur [...].